# Excel VBA Color cell under month and year depends on cell value (date) in other sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have Two Sheets:

EXCEL
[image]

EXCEL2

RESULT
[image: RESULT]

Basically What ever date is in image (EXCEL 2) in front of Names same date will represent in form of color in front of name under same month and year in excel sheet two that is (image EXCEL).

Sorry I can not able to figure out any code or anything totally blank. Hope get some help here Thanks
RESULT SOMTHING LIKE IN IMAGE 3 if date is changed in Sheet color and month should update as new date

Comment: Maybe you could add another image, showing us the expected result?

Comment: @karma I corrected image 2 with correct dates as expected result

Comment: In Excel2 image, Mr. A test - test1 - test2 are all in April 2023. How come the expected result in RESULT image, under year 2023, Mr. A get May for test2 and get Oct for test1 ? The same thing with Mr. B in Excel2 image, Mr. B test is oct 2024, test1 is also Oct 2024 and test2 is Feb 2024. How come Mr. B in RESULT image, under year 2024, his test1 is in Nov2024 and his test2 is in Apr 2025 ? Please CMIIW.

Comment: By only seeing the RESULT image, doesn't that mean that the Excel2 image actually should show that Mr.A test is Apr2023, test1 is Oct2023 and test2 is May2023 ? And Mr. B test is Oct2024, test1 is Nov2024 and test2 is Apr2025 ? Please CMIIW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly.....

Before running the macro, the condition of the two sheets (sh1 and sh2) is something like this :

[image]

The expected result after running the sub is like image below

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim dt As Date: Dim t0 As Date: Dim t1 As Date: Dim t2 As Date
Dim rgT As Range: Dim rgN As Range: Dim c As Range: Dim cell as Range

With Sheets("sh2")
    Set rgT = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
End With

With Sheets("sh1")
    .Range("A2:Z1000").Interior.Color = xlNone
    Set rgN = .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlConstants)
End With

dt = "1-jan-2023"

For Each cell In rgT

    t0 = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    t1 = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    t2 = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value

    Set c = rgN.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t0) + 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t1) + 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t2) + 1).Interior.Color = vbBlack
    End If
    
Next

End Sub
```

rgT variable is the range of column A in sh2. It assume there'll be no blank cell in the whole table (cell A2:D6).

rgN variable is the range of column A in sh1.

Basically, the code just get the month difference from the starting "benchmark" date with each date in the test/test1/test2 in sh2. In this case example, the "benchmark" is the dt variable which value is 01-January-2023.

It loop to all the cell within the rgT, and check if the looped cell value is found in rgN as c variable then it fill the needed cell with the needed color.

FYI, if the sh1 looks like in your image, then you need to add 2 for each c.offset because there is one column in between the cell with the name and the starting "benchmark" cell.

Comment: It is working like magic thanks ;)

Comment: what if there is duplicate date and in that case if I want to put next color in same column next row(consider in sheet each name has three rows for duplicate date) and it shows all three colors on same date.

Comment: If each name has 3 available rows, if I may suggest : put each test in different row for each name. Then you can just change the row offset in `c.offset` for each test. Example : for test1 `c.Offset(1, DateDiff("m", dt, t1) + 1).Interior.Color = vbRed` and for test2 `c.Offset(2, DateDiff("m", dt, t2) + 1).Interior.Color = vbBlack`

Comment: You mean like this "code" If Not c Is Nothing Then
        c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t0) + 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        c.Offset(1, DateDiff("m", dt, t1) + 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        c.Offset(2, DateDiff("m", dt, t2) + 1).Interior.Color = vbBlack
        c.Offset(3, DateDiff("m", dt, t3) + 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        c.Offset(4, DateDiff("m", dt, t4) + 1).Interior.Color = vbBlue
        c.Offset(5, DateDiff("m", dt, t5) + 1).Interior.Color = vbCyan
    End If but that is not working

Comment: Please define "that is not working" ? Your code above means that there are 6 test. So you should make additional variable which are t3, t4, t5 before writing `c.Offset(3, DateDiff("m", dt, t3) + 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow`. Then if there are 6 test, then each name in sh1 must have 6 available rows. But if the test is keep on changing, for example : this time 6 test but next time 10000 test - then before running the  macro you should prepare the available rows for each name in sh1 according with how many test there are in sh2

Comment: I posted new question because I was getting very mixed up [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75155102/21026307) if you see that you will understand

Comment: Yes, your new question is different with this question although similar. But the biggest different is, in this question : the cell for the name in your first image **is not merged** frrom multiple rows, while in your new question, the cell for the name is a 6 rows merged. At the time c.offset(1, ....) ---> because the c is a merged cell, then the offset will go to the next row after the merged cell. if c is a merged cell A1:A3 .... c.offset(1,...) will be of course A4, not A2. But, if you unmerged the cell, put each name on the first row, then it should work.

Comment: Thank when I unmerged and tried it worked as I was expecting.

Comment: You still can have the name in a merged rows. The trick is : offset the row to 0 first while offseting the column according to the month difference... after that, then offset the row to the next available row. Please have a look to my comment in your new question.