# Cell background Colors reference to dates on other sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I Have Two Sheets. [image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]

The code I use works perfectly but for single row as per expected result If date is duplicate next color should come under same month. but with this code it is taking the last color and putting it.

[image: Expected resullt]

This is code I am using

```
Sub ColorsCell()

Dim dt As Date: Dim t0 As Date: Dim t1 As Date: Dim t2 As Date: Dim t3 As Date: Dim t4 As Date: Dim t5 As Date
Dim rgT As Range: Dim rgN As Range: Dim c As Range: Dim cell As Range

With Sheets("Sheet5")
    Set rgT = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
End With

With Sheets("Sheet3")
    .Range("B6:bu11, b13:bu18, B20:bu25, b27:bu32, B34:bu39").Interior.Color = xlNone
    Set rgN = .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlConstants)
End With

dt = "1-jan-2023"

For Each cell In rgT

    t0 = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    t1 = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    t2 = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
    t3 = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    t4 = cell.Offset(0, 5).Value
    t5 = cell.Offset(0, 6).Value

    Set c = rgN.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t0) + 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t1) + 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t2) + 1).Interior.Color = vbBlack
        c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t3) + 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t4) + 1).Interior.Color = vbBlue
        c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t5) + 1).Interior.Color = vbCyan
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: can you rephrase your question?

Comment: @Maya I need to change Interior color of cells in Sheet1 and per dates in Sheet2 in from of same names but if date(month and year) is duplicate than all will come under same column of months and year(each row(cell) with it's color.

Comment: Again, if you don't mind that each test color will be in independent row, then with the name in a merge cell like in your image, you can have something like `c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t0) + 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen:
        c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t1) + 1).Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = vbRed:
        c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t2) + 1).Offset(2, 0).Interior.Color = vbBlack` So, the code is not offseting the row in the first place, but the column... then it offseting the row. But again, the result : each color for each test will all fill each 6 available rows for each name.

Comment: @karma yes it is working perfect thanks How I can accept your answer on this question or how I can marked it answered?

Comment: That's OK. I think you can post your own answer to your own question and mark it as answered :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I unmerged the cells with name than this code is working

```
Sub ColorsCell()
Dim dt As Date: Dim t0 As Date: Dim t1 As Date: Dim t2 As Date: Dim t3 As Date: Dim t4 As Date: Dim t5 As Date
Dim rgT As Range: Dim rgN As Range: Dim c As Range: Dim cell As Range
With Sheets("Sheet5")
    Set rgT = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
End With
With Sheets("Sheet3")
    .Range("B6:bu11, b13:bu18, B20:bu25, b27:bu32, B34:bu39").Interior.Color = xlNone
    Set rgN = .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlConstants)
End With
dt = "1-jan-2023"
For Each cell In rgT
    t0 = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    t1 = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    t2 = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
    t3 = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    t4 = cell.Offset(0, 5).Value
    t5 = cell.Offset(0, 6).Value
    Set c = rgN.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not c Is Nothing Then
   c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t0) + 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen:
   c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t1) + 1).Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color = vbRed:
   c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t2) + 1).Offset(2, 0).Interior.Color = vbBlack
   c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t3) + 1).Offset(3, 0).Interior.Color = vbYellow
   c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t4) + 1).Offset(4, 0).Interior.Color = vbBlue
   c.Offset(0, DateDiff("m", dt, t5) + 1).Offset(5, 0).Interior.Color = vbCyan
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks to @karma